# show fields depending if is printing or not in a report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report that is going to be printed in a pre-formatted sheet (like an invoice). I want the user to be able to see the report as it would appear on the paper, but print only the values for each field on the sheet. I know each field has a property "hide based on an expression"; but how can I distinguish between printing and on screen visualization. I am using c# and report viewer on vs 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign the hidden field something like this "=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive".  Read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx) for more information on rendering report layout.